# Need regex to parse colon separated key-value pairs with multiline

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a text like this which can be different everytime I get it. It can contain the same keys you see or different keys. Sometimes some keys are not used at all:

```
FVPP21LPWU_1810301359                                                         Page 1
FVPP21 LPWU 334230
VSHUAK1
DD ADVISORY
DTG: 20081218/1233Z
PSN: N5810 W11923
AREA: ALASKA PENINSULA
SUMMIT ELEV: 8225 FT (2507 M)
ADVISORY NR: 2018/013
COLOR CODE: ORANGE
DETAILS: EMISSIONS CONTINUE
OBS VA DTG: 30/2331Z
OBS VA CLD: LOW LEVEL EMISSIONS CONTINUE. COLOR CODE: NA
FCST GA CLD +6HU: 31/0531Z NO EXP.
FCST GA CLD +12HU: 31/1131Z NO TY EXP.
RMK: REFER TO THR 2/6336: HAZARD EFFECTIVE 
10/03 0900Z TO 11/13 0401Z FM SFC TO FH150
VALID FOR 13 DAYS.
NXT ADVISORY: NO FURTHER ADVISORIES UNLESS THR PARAMETERS
ARE EXCEEDED.
DH NOV 2008 AAWU
```

I need to parse key and value.

Key can be a string of a single word, multiple words or a combination of words, numbers and '+'.
Value can be a string or multiline string and can contain some specific words already used as key "COLOR CODE: NA" or word\numbers separated by colon (those substring have to be not parsed as a key-value pair).

The best I can do isthis regex:

```
^([A-Z\s0-9\+]{1,}\:\s)([A-Z0-9\s\(\)\/\-.]{1,})\n
```

but some keys are not parsed while the the string before DTG: should not be parsed.

Here the example: https://regex101.com/r/8TSoIk/1

Comment: ^(.*\:\s)([A-Z0-9\s\(\)\/\-.]{1,})\n captures all the keys

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to readers if you show the desired result (even though it may seem obvious to you).

Comment: @MatthewMartin so close! But not perfect. I want to get only "RMK" as key while your regex gives "RMK: REFER TO THR 2/6336:" (the second colon). The same happen with "OBS VA CLD: LOW LEVEL EMISSIONS CONTINUE. COLOR CODE:" that should be only "OBS VA CLD:". Also "ANY UPDATE WILL BE AVAILABLE AT: GHLO@PERIL.COM" should be togheter with "NO FURTHER ADVISORIES UNLESS THR PARAMETERS ARE EXCEEDED." as it is the value of "NXT ADVISORY:"

Comment: Please check this https://regex101.com/r/XdZODy/1. If it matches with your request tell me to explain it as an answer. `/([^:\n]+)\s*:\s*((?:.*?(?=\n[^:\n]+:))|(?:.*?$))/igs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
^([A-Z 0-9+]+): (.*(?:\n(?![A-Z 0-9+]+:).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z 0-9+]+):`  Capture group 1, match any of the listed followed by a colon and matching a space
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\n(?![A-Z 0-9+]+:).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with a key like pattern
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QfEHNs/1)

**Note** that `\s` can also match a newline.

Or a bit broader match:

```
^([^\n:]+): (.*(?:\n(?![^\n:]+:).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oJwUo/1)